# How to access type methods that are not defined in interface?

Tags: go, go-interface

I have interface that requires its implementor to have Click method.
However, the type FakeTicker that implements this interface also implements Tick method in addition to Click method.

```
package main



type Ticker interface{  
  Click() string 
}

type FakeTicker struct{ 
   val string }

func (f FakeTicker) Click() string {    
   return f.val 
}

func (f FakeTicker) Tick() int {    return 1 }

func main() {   
  var clocker Ticker    
  clocker = FakeTicker{"Val"}   
  clocker.Tick()    
}
```

Here I get the following error "clocker.Tick undefined (type Ticker has no field or method Tick)"

I understand that the interface only has method Click() but since FakeWriter is implementing the interface, 
Shouldn't it be able to call its own method Tick()?

Comment: @p-ray *"Shouldn't it be able to call its **own** method Tick()?"* It should be able and it also is able. The error is not from *it* not being able to call `Tick` but from the *"user"* of `clocker` not being able to call `Tick`.

Comment: @mkopriva As mentioned in the accepted answer, I think it needs to be converted to implementing struct.

Comment: What I meant by my comment is that `FakeTicker` can call its *own* `Tick` method, for example from inside of its *own* `Click` method. `func (f FakeTicker) Click() string { f.Tick(); return f.val }`. I'm just being a little pedantic here, feel free to ignore me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the interface only has method Click() but since FakeWriter is implementing the interface, Shouldn't it be able to call its own method Tick()?

Since your `clocker` variable is defined as the `Ticker` interface, you only have the methods defined on that interface. If you would like to access the `Tick` method, you will have to change to the `FakeTicker` type.

In this case, you can use type assertion.

```
func main() {   
    var clocker Ticker    
    clocker = FakeTicker{"Val"}
    clocker.Click()
    fake := clocker.(FakeTicker)
    fake.Tick()    
}
```

You should note that the type assertion will cause a panic when the assertion fails if you don't use the version with two return types (`fake, ok := clocker.(FakeTicker)`).

Answer (score 4):

You would need to convert the interface{} to FakeTicker

```
package main

type Ticker interface {
    Click() string
}

type FakeTicker struct {
    val string
}

func (f FakeTicker) Click() string {
    return f.val
}

func (f FakeTicker) Tick() int { return 1 }

func main() {
    var clocker Ticker
    clocker = FakeTicker{"Val"}
    fakeTicker := clocker.(FakeTicker)
    fakeTicker.Tick()
}
```